# error with the command bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compilation, compiler-errors, bundle

Hello developers I am trouble 
When I write the command:

bundle exec rake assets:precompile

the command return me :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /var/www/nubedianWebSite/Rakefile:7)
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /var/www/nubedianWebSite/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:48:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/...]
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/var/www/nubedianWebSite/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don´t know how I can fix it.
I hope yours answers soon.
thanks for all.
Antonio

Comment: please provide `Gemfile`

Comment: First do bundle install, then do assets precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output says

```
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Have you got sqlite3 in your Gemfile?

If not - edit your "Gemfile" and add the line:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Make sure to run "bundle install" after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

answer is mentioned in your log, `Please install the sqlite3 adapter`, run the following command

```
gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
```